# Can you assign a variable in a SELECT, and then using it later in the same SELECT?

Tags: mysql, alias

Here is a query I'm trying to write:

```
SELECT I.*, 
       IF(MAX(B.`amount`) != 0, MAX(B.`amount`), I.`start`) AS `current_bid`, 
       `current_bid` * 1.05 AS `min_bid`
       ...
```

I am getting the error "Unknown column 'current_bid'". I am assuming it is because I just created the current column in the line before. Is there anyway I can make this query work the way I want it to? I guess one way to get it to work would be to use two if statements that say basically the same thing, like this:

```
SELECT I.*, 
       IF(MAX(B.`amount`) != 0, MAX(B.`amount`), I.`start`) AS `current_bid`, 
       IF(MAX(B.`amount`) != 0, MAX(B.`amount`) * 1.05, I.`start` * 1.05) AS `min_id`
       ...
```

But that seems horribly inefficient.

Also, is there a way I can assign `current` without calculating `MAX(B.amount)` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    C.CURRENT_BID,
    C.CURRENT_BID * 1.05 AS MIN_BID
FROM
    (
        SELECT MAX(B.AMOUNT) AS CURRENT_BID FROM ...
    ) C
```

I'm pretty sure that nested queries get executed first, so that you can use their results.  Whereas different columns in the same query are treated as concurrent, so you can't make them dependent on each other.

Comment: You beat me to it ... I think that's the only way.  Does seems strange though, why wouldn't SQL have a built-in way to alias a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference `current_bid` nor any aliased column in another column. There are two ways to proceed:

1. You copy the whole calculation whenever you want to use that value (most efficient, less readable)
2. You use a derived table (less efficient, more readable)

In the latter case you should do something like:

```
select current_bid from (
    IF(MAX(B.`amount`) != 0, MAX(B.`amount`), I.`start`) AS `current_bid`...
) s
```

I'd like to make emphasis that the derived table will perform a scan of all the rows and that will be less efficient. Most of the times it is better to copy the formula.

PS: If you're going for the first option, note that you can write your second `IF` this way:

```
IF(MAX(B.`amount`) = 0, I.`start`, MAX(B.`amount`)) * 1.05 `min_id`
```

Which is a little bit more readable.